# Error sending data to web browser in python

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, websocket, tornado

When I test my module in console no errors are given, but when I try to receive the data from a browser I get an error message:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mile' referenced before assignment
```

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
while cursor.alive:                
    try:
        doc = yield motor.Op(cursor.next_object)
        if doc:
            mileInfo={'time': doc['time_normal']}
            print doc['term']

            if doc['term'] == 'abc':
                event = 'abc'
            elif doc['term'] == 'def':
                event = 'def'
            elif doc['term'] == 'xyz':
                 event = 'xyz'    
            else:
                 event = 'rst'


             if not doc['coordinates']:
                 placeName = doc['place']['full_name']                          
                 mile = from_name(placeName, event)
                 print 'from Name: ' ,mile, 'term: ', event, doc['place']['full_name'] 
             else: 
                 mile = get_coords(doc['coordinates']['coordinates'], event)
                print 'from coordinates: ',mile, 'term: ', event, 'location:', doc['coordinates']['coordinates']                                                                  

               mileInfo['miles'] = mile
               self.write_message(json.dumps(mileInfo, default = json_util.default))

        except StopIteration:
            pass

    except:
            traceback.print_exc()
```

I'm confused why I get this error only from the web browser.

Thanks

Comment: Your indentation is terrible; it could be that that's the cause of your problems.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm surprised it runs. Wouldn't it fail on compilation for some of this?

Comment: Thanks for replying. The indentation was from copying the code over from my workspace. I think it got altered. This is the only traceback I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to sort the error by declaring a global variable 'mile' and also by cleaning up the indentation (thanks for the suggestion @MartijnPieters). So I inserted a global variable here:

```
while cursor.alive:
    try:
        doc = yield motor.Op(cursor.next_object)
        global mile

        if doc: ...............
```